# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException при использовании com.j256.ormlite во время обновления

Tags: java, sqlite, orm

При попытке обновить запись в БД через `Dao` выскакивает ошибка:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run update-id stmt on object ImageRecord(imageEmulator=BOCHS, imageOSType=LINUX, imageType=IMAGE_BIOS, description=22222222222, name=aaaaaaaaaaaa, lastModified=Wed Jul 06 15:38:17 MSK 2016, id=3): UPDATE `images` SET `id` = ? WHERE `id` = ?
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedUpdateId.execute(MappedUpdateId.java:51)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.updateId(StatementExecutor.java:459)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.updateId(BaseDaoImpl.java:365)
    at com.dugin.rostislav.image.database.sqlite.SQLiteDBHelper.changeImage(SQLiteDBHelper.java:59)
    at com.dugin.rostislav.image.database.ImageStorageHelper.changeImage(ImageStorageHelper.java:14)
    at com.dugin.rostislav.Main.main(Main.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not assign object '3' to field FieldType:name=id,class=ImageRecord
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignField(FieldType.java:560)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedUpdateId.execute(MappedUpdateId.java:42)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.dugin.rostislav.image.database.sqlite.ImageRecord.id to java.lang.String
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:98)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignField(FieldType.java:558)
    ... 11 more
```

---

Как объект БД я использую данный класс (`@Getter` и `@Setter` - это аннотации библиотеки Lombok, они генерируют геттеры и сеттеры, а `@ToString` - распечатывает все поля при вызове `.toString`):

```
@ToString
@DatabaseTable(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
public class ImageRecord extends BaseDaoEnabled {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_EMULATOR_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageEmulator imageEmulator;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_OS_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageOSType imageOSType;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageType imageType;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)
    private String description;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_NAME)
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED, version = true, dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
    private Date lastModified;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id; //Auto generated DB column
}
```

Вставка происходит так:

```
imagesDao.updateId(imageRecond, imageRecord.getId());
```

`imageRecord` - это объект с полями:

```
imageEmulator=BOCHS
imageOsType=LINUX
imageType=IMAGE_BIOS
name=aaaaaaaaaaaa
description=22222222222
lastModified=1467809082541
id = 1
```

---

Почему БД пытается вставить `id` в какое-то строковое поле и как это исправить?

Comment: Если ID у вас прописано как генерируемое, то попробуйте оставить его пустым/равным нулю. И вообще - зачем ID менять?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я его и не меняю...

Comment: А что тогда делает метод updateId, принимающий ID?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, обновляет запись по указанному id, по смыслу.

Comment: Добавьте код этого метода. Вообще, если ID известно и есть в обновляемом объекте, то второй аргумент не нужен. Если же ID неизвестно, то тем паче. И там таки опечатка, что аргументы с разными именами вы передаёте?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, опечатка. Код метода не мой, я его не писал, но могу скинуть (когда домой вернусь). А вот то, что id не нужно передавать, я не подумал. Вернусь домой и попробую без id.

Comment: У вас ошибка в DAO классе, который в методе updateId пытается изменить id у записи в БД: `UPDATE 'images' SET 'id' = ? WHERE 'id' = ?` и скорее всего это поле id - первичный ключ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну... Без id оно работает. Ну... Не работает, но ошибку не выдает. Только оно теперь пытается обновить по всем полям, беря их, как ключ (если я правильно понял, с SQL не сильно дружу).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Вы оказались правы и передавать id мне не нужно было. Видимо, `updateId` в прямом смысле означает обновить id. Рядом был метод `deleteById`, вот я и сопоставил... В общем - в ответ!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, и не подскажете, данную строку чем можно пропарсить, на JSON вроде не похожа: `[ImageRecord(imageEmulator=BOCHS, imageOSType=LINUX, imageType=IMAGE_BIOS, description=qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq, name=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, id=3), ImageRecord(imageEmulator=BOCHS, imageOSType=LINUX, imageType=IMAGE_BIOS, description=qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq, name=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, id=4)]`?

Comment: @bukashka101, вообще на json похоже... А распарсить можно сначала вырезав элементы меж скобок, потом разбив по запятой с проблелом, а потом по =

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, фух, оказалось БД возвращает сразу `List` с нужными мне объектами в виде `Object`. А я сразу не понял, чего мне странную строку возвращает, когда я пытаюсь этот лист распечатать..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то не так в методе обновления ID или в модели данных или в таблице. Ошибка говорит о том, что нужно int а получен String

Если ID известно и есть в обновляемом объекте, то второй аргумент не нужен. Если же ID неизвестно, то тем паче. В любом случае менять ID в таблицах - плохая идея и делать так не надо. Если в этом возникла нужда - значит вы что-то не так делаете.